# Histogram With Percent Split For Each Bar?

Tags: d3.js

Just discovered this incredible library, but am a bit overwhelmed with all the options.  Consider a visualization of players, let's say basketball players.  We want to compare them across on a number of qualities, say passing, scoring, rebounding, etc.

On any given quality, we compare each players score relative to the other's.  So if one player had 2 points while the other only had 1 point, the first player would get 66% and the other player 33%.  If there scores were equal, they'd each get 50%.

The qualities, however, vary in importance.  So now imagine each quality as a histogram bar.  It's height will tell you how important that quality is relative to the other qualities, ie, relative to the other histogram bar.  And each bar will be shaded half one color, half another color, showing you each player's relative score on that quality.

1. First Question: Could I create such a graph using D3?  Could I make the histogram horizontal?
2. Is there a better way to visualize these two simultaneous comparisons?

Thanks!

### EDIT:

I found [this example](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/09/06/us/politics/convention-word-counts.html#america) which could work perfectly for my situations -- size of circles showing importance of quality, and division of circles into red/blue showing each player's score.  But I can't figure out what kind of graph that is?

Comment: If you can imagine it, you can build it with d3.js.  That's the best thing about the library, it's not a typical charting library - it's a data driven graphics library.  I'm not a data visualization expert so I'm not sure the best way to visualize the data, I'll leave that for somebody else to answer. Have you seen http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/06/11/sports/basketball/nba-shot-analysis.html? This is possible with d3.js and I thought it was pretty neat.

Comment: Thats awesome - do you know how they did that photo effect with the transition? @Bill

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much the coolest thing ever.  I actually found an example that would be pretty perfect for my case, though not what I was imagining at first: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/09/06/us/politics/convention-word-counts.html#america.  Now where do I find the docs on building that kind of graph -- do you know what it's called?

Comment: Each data point just goes through a transition in size, color, and location.  Basically each point has a set of values to make the face and a set of values to show the data.  You then update the points with a transition (see http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html) when animates the change from one to the other smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bubble chart is a force directed layout of nodes, I don't think there is a special name for the fact that the nodes show a relationship between two data points.  Maybe if Mike sees this he can let you know since he is the one that built the example for the Times.

There are quite a few tricks to get this to work, you can check out the code at http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2012/09/04/convention-speeches/ac823b240e99920e91945dbec49f35b268c09c38/index.js which has thankfully been left unminified.

Comment: Bill I'm reading that tutorial you linked to.  I see what you mean when you said this is different from other js graphics libraries.  It seems that rather than a pre-defined set of graph types that you can configure with various options, we are provided something much more flexible, a language or toolset for creating your own custom graphs.  Is this bubble chart one such custom creation?

Comment: Exactly.  You can see a simpler version at http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/bubble.html.